# VSCode configuation issues - on Anaconda :: debugging-complaints from the system

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

while starting VSCode on Anaconda i just ran into some issues.
**Note**: i run VsCode 1.52.1 - in Anaconda on Win 10

In earlier times i had VSCode installed with platform.io - but this was long time ago. now i wanted to execude a python script - but this did not work - i got back the following image
image

and then i choosed "open Launch.json " - see the according image:

[image]

but i am not sure what to do here?!

```
/ / PIO Unified Debugger


//

// Documentation: https://docs.platformio.org/page/plus/debugging.html

// Configuration: https://docs.platformio.org/page/projectconf/section_env_debug.html

{

    "version": "0.2.0",

    "configurations": [

        {

            "type": "platformio-debug",

            "request": "launch",

            "name": "PIO Debug",

            "executable": "c:/Users/tarifa/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/ESP/.pio/build/esp32dev/firmware.elf",

            "projectEnvName": "esp32dev",

            "toolchainBinDir": "C:/Users/tarifa/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa32/bin",

            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",

            "preLaunchTask": {

                "type": "PlatformIO",

                "task": "Pre-Debug"

            }

        },

        {

            "type": "platformio-debug",

            "request": "launch",

            "name": "PIO Debug (skip Pre-Debug)",

            "executable": "c:/Users/tarifa/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/ESP/.pio/build/esp32dev/firmware.elf",

            "projectEnvName": "esp32dev",

            "toolchainBinDir": "C:/Users/tarifa/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa32/bin",

            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"

        }

    ]

}
```

well i guess that i have to do some more configurations of the VSCode
btw. it seems to be so, that i can update /& upgrade VScode form Version 1.52.xy to newer versions!?

**update:**

[image]
i editet according to stevents hint - now i am going to test.

i still struggle with the settings - i guess that i have to skip and throw all the esp32 and all the other microcontroller /platformio-things away.. They cause lots of issues

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to annotate `preLaunchTask`:

```
    "preLaunchTask": {

        "type": "PlatformIO",

        "task": "Pre-Debug"

    }
```

Comment: hello dear Steven, many many thanks, i  editet according to your hint - now i am going to test.

Comment: editet according to stevents hint - now i am going to test.

i still struggle with the settings - i guess that i have to skip and throw all the esp32 and all the other microcontroller /platformio-things away.. They cause lots of issues

Look forward to hear from you again .- have a great day

Comment: Very sorry for late. In fact, I am not familiar with the configuration you take. I am just taking the normal configuration to debug the python. You can refer to the official docs here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging.  In brief, click the 'Add Configuration' Button, then choose the python category and then choose the specific type of your project. Very sorry for the late response again.

Comment: hi there Steven - many thanks. I will do as adviced and will try it out. Many thanks for all you do!